# halfspaces question

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry

How do I find the supporting halfspace inequality to epigraph of 
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{|x|+1}$$
at point $(1,0.5)$

Comment: It looks like you want a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. But what is $x^2$ in the numerator^

Comment: What? Could you explain more?

Comment: What is $x$? How many coordinates? I guess $2$ since you mention the point $(1,0.5)$. But then what is $x^2$ at the numerator?

Comment: x is a single x-axis value... for $x=1$, $f(1) = 0.5$

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$, we have
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad f'(x)=\frac{x^2+2x}{(x+1)^2}.
$$
Hence $f'(1)=\frac{3}{4}$ and an equation of the tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(1,f(1))$ is 
$$y=f'(1)(x-1)+f(1)=\frac{3}{4}(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{1}{4}.$$ 
An inequality defining the halfspace above this tangent is therefore
$$
y\geq  \frac{3}{4}x-\frac{1}{4}.
$$
[See here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2ona7gz2bq) for a picture of the graph and the tangent.